# Is there a way to get the red artifact in Undertale?

Tags: undertale

My brother has been trying different ways of getting the artifact without the Annoying Dog consuming it, but has been unsuccessful. I'm kind of curious as well. The artifact is obviously a throwing ball, but I kind of want to know the description for the artifact itself, and if you need to cheat to get it... If it even is an item in the code, too.

Answer (score 9):

The "artifact" is a red herring. After the scene that plays when you

> drop the dog,

you receive a different item instead, which is the actual reward of the room.

Regarding the item's purpose...

> Try using the item while you have some empty space in your inventory, it will occasionally give you a healing item. Also, check the descriptions for each one, it changes.

Comment: You can also use the item to give yourself infinite money, in a sense.

Comment: Assuming you find a place to sell items in the game.

Comment: @Zibbobz hOI! sell? mikey has nO ideuh wut you meenz :3

Comment: hOI! I'm Chupi!

Answer (score 2):

No, the artifact doesn't exist within the games files.
If you somehow manage to edit your inventory to remove the dog, and interact with the artifact, the game simply says `*(This will never happen.)` and if you try to put the dog in the box the game says `*(The box is aclog with the hair of a dog)`. The dog gives a more useful item anyways, because once you reach tem shop you can use it to have infinite money, and you can use it as a last resort for healing items in battle, because when used, the dog residue gives you dog residue and dog salad, and fills your inventory with it. Dog salad heals 2,10,30 or all HP (hit poodles) when used in or out of battle.

Comment: Lol "Hit Poodles"

Answer (score -6):

I'm unsure if this is possible, but I think if you leave that room alone all the way until you end up at MTT resort use the hot dog to get that item from the last room and then go back to the artifact room. There may be a way to get it.  The item does claim to stop dog magic or something.

Answer (score -6):

This is an idea that may work but I haven't personally tried it and I dont know if anyone has done it before:

When you get to the piano and input the proper code, dont go in the room with the artifact. Instead, progress forward until Alphys uprades your phone to have dimensional boxes A and B. Go back into the room with the artifact and try to put the annoying dog in one of the dimensional boxes. I hope this works, I'm gonna go try it too.

Hope I Helped!

Comment: Speculation is generally discouraged. This has also already been proven false: "It is impossible to put the Annoying Dog into a box, as trying to use a dimensional box through the cellphone will display the text "The box is clogged with the hair of a dog", and leaving the room with the Annoying Dog still in the inventory will make it disappear until reentering." http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Annoying_Dog#Piano_Room

Comment: Alright, thank you for letting me know. And I understand that the dog only gets in your inventory when in the room, I meant to say to go back to the room afterwards. Has there ever been a recorded way of getting the artifact? The dog is so annoying...

Comment: See my answer below. The "artifact" is not a thing that can be gotten.